# Set database connection timeout in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, oracle11g

I am using activerecord-oracle_enhanced-enhanced (1.6.6) gem to connect with the oracle database from the rails app (rails 4.2.5)
I need to set the Database connection timeout.
Below are the setting used in database.yml file,

```
development:  
    adapter: oracle_enhanced  
    host: 10.10.10.58  
    port: 1521  
    database: TUTSDB  
    username: tutsadmin  
    password: Tuts1234  
    encoding: utf8  
    timeout: 15000
```

I have specified the timeout to be 15 sec.
Even after doing this we are getting the below error:
**(ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError) "could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds (waited 5.000144774 seconds)**.
It is waiting for the connection only for 5 seconds (which is the default timeout value). Ideally it should wait for 15 sec.

Comment: Just how slow is your database? That sounds like a broken configuration if it takes that long. Is it resolving reverse DNS names on connect?

Comment: No. There are many connections due to which it is unable to make new connection. It waits for 5 seconds and throws the above error.

Comment: Make sure you're testing your app in development mode. You've set the timeout in the development mode here. Or set it in all modes and then test.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Timeouts guides](https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced#timeouts) it seems that you have to set the timeout otherwise:

```
development:
  database: "(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
    (CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(TCP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe))
  )"
```

Comment: Is the connect_timeout in seconds?

Comment: From the doc it seems like that